# XML documents must start and end within the same entity help me

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="290dp" />

        <TextClock
            android:id="@+id/textClock1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="146dp"
            android:text="@+id/textclock"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="100sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can I have some help on this I'm really confused would really appreciate some advice. I was just cleaning up my code when this error appeared. I have no idea on how to fix

Comment: You didn't close your Relative Layout.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because you didn't close `RelativeLayout`  tag in your xml file,so add `</RelativeLayout>`at the end of xml file.

**You don't need to add two relative layout where one parent layout is useless**

So simply replace in your code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

with

```
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >
```

**Second Option** is
Remove your `xml` code and saved the `xml file`. After that,replace it with the above code and save. The error will be gone. It is probably a remnant from the time when "automatically build project" enabled.

Comment: I replaced the code but still gives me the same error :/